# triple integral: how do I graph the solid?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let's say I'm given a triple integral such as $\int_0^1\int_0^{4-2y}\int_0^{4-2y-z} dx dz dy$ and I need to graph the solid based on the bounds... is there some "algorithm" I can follow?

I understand y "moves" between $0$ and $2$, z "moves" between $0$ and $4-2y$ and x "moves" between $0$ and $4-2y-z$ but how do I plot that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lower bounds $x=0,y=0,z=0$ are the $yz,xz,$ and $xy$ planes respectively. The upper bounds $y=1$, $z=4-2y$, and $x=4-2y-z$ are also planes. Here I plotted the first three, then added the next three. We see that the intersection bounds some region. The final plot shows that region more clearly.

[image: plots]

The Mathematica code for generating these plots:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 {x == 0, y == 0, z == 0, x == 4 - 2 y - z, y == 1,z == 4 - 2 y}, 
 {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]

RegionPlot3D[
 x < 4 - 2 y - z && y < 1 && z < 4 - 2 y, 
 {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1.5}, {z,0, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> 5]
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I'm still confused when it comes to the 3rd dimension. Since the equation is $4-2y-z$ wouldn't the plane be $x=4-2y-z$? And in that case, when I plot it it would be $z=4-2y-x$?